# Structure of the automorphism group of a Riemann surface

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, cv.complex-variables, riemann-surfaces

I was wondering if anything is known about the possible structure of $\mathrm{Aut}(S)$ for a Riemann surface $S$. More precisely, are there known obstructions for a finite group $G$ to be such an automorphism group?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no obstructions.

In fact, every finite group is isomorphic to the full automorphism group $\textrm{Aut}(S)$ of some compact Riemann surface $S$ (of genus at least $2$).

Moreover, $S$ may be chosen so that the quotient Riemann surface $S/\textrm{Aut}(S)$ has any preassigned genus.

For a reference, see Theorem 4 in the paper by L. Greenberg *[Maximal Fuchsian groups](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183525375)*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. Volume **69**, Number 4 (1963), 569-573.